# updating from react router 3 to 4.1.1, how would I seperate my routes from my app.jsx?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4

In React Router 3.0.5 the site was working fine, but when I tried to update to React Router 4.1.1 I got a few errors. I'm trying to have the main route be "/" where it goes to the app component, otherwise it goes to the others listed.

I get an error of Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `history` is marked as required in `Router`, but its value is `undefined`.
    in Router

and this error:
Router.js:31 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined

Here's my code
App.jsx:

```js
import React from 'react';
import LeftPane from './LeftPane.jsx';
import RightPane from './RightPane.jsx';
import CenterPane from './CenterPane.jsx';
import TopPane from './TopPane.jsx';
import Models from './Models.jsx';
import Projects from './Projects.jsx';
import Contact from './Contact.jsx';
import Router from 'react-router';
import axios from 'axios';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { modelBucket: [] };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    axios({
      method: 'POST',
      url: '/modelcall'
    })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log('this is the axios call from models.jsx (the response) :', response);
      this.setState({modelBucket: response});
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log('this is an error from the axios call in models.jsx', error);
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <div>
            <TopPane />
          </div>
          <div className="container-fluid text-center">    
            <div className="row content">
              <div className="col-sm-12 text-center"> 
                {this.props.children}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

and here's my routes.js page:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './components/App.jsx';
import Models from './components/Models.jsx';
import Projects from './components/Projects.jsx';
import Contact from './components/Contact.jsx';
import About from './components/About.jsx';
import CenterPane from './components/CenterPane.jsx';

export default (
      <Router exact path="/" component={App}>
         <Route path="/models" component={Models} />
         <Route path="/projects" component={Projects} />
         <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
         <Route path="/about" component={About} />
      </Router>
);
```

I tried to follow some tutorials online for react router 4.1.1 but it seems each one is slightly different. Some use BrowserRouter, some use hashRouter, some just use Router.... I'm lost.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it should be something like this. Make sure you list them down starting from the most specific to the most generic one. Anyway Browser History and hash history was there in the previous version too. Anyway Hash History is the preferred approach.

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';


ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/models" component={Models} />
            <Route path="/projects" component={Projects} />
            <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
            <Route path="/about" component={About} />
            <Route path="/" component={App} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>
  , document.querySelector('.container'));
```

Hope this helps. Happy Coding !

Comment: What's the provider store, is that redux?

Comment: Also, when I go back to the App page, do i still go with the this.children.props to get those components to work?

Comment: I'm not currently using redux